# Java Open Files on Windows/NTFS - not closing

Tags: java, windows, file-io, java-7, windows-server-2012-r2

Problem:  Java App with embedded database. On Linux/Mac closing the database also closes all the open files. On Windows, I find that the database will stop cleanly but the files it is using are held open by the JVM. ( proc explorer lists them, can't delete or rename them)

I am guessing the difference between the behavior on Windows and *ix is down to how the JVM interacts with NTFS.

any suggestions on how to do one of the following:

1. Close a file that was opened by a thread which has now terminated?
2. Change NTFS settings or JVm property to ensure the closure?

Also open to other debug ideas: jstack -l, visualvm, process explorer and running in IDE with break points to introduce pauses etc. have not helped other than to further my Java education on Windows.

Thanks, FITCS

Comment: can you fix the embedded database? i.e. do you get at any point a file handle (or File in java) in your app (w.r.t. 1. you can close any file from any thread at any time)? otherwise can you execute the db in its own jvm process (that would release all open file handles for you)?

Comment: Sounds to me like a not closed file handle. Are you able to post a small example which demonstrates the behaviour?

Comment: Why don't you name the "embedded database"?